# Add dynamic cells to static table view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a form that i have add some data. i am using table view controller and text fields(One text field for one cell). so i want to add some dynamic table cells for that table.

Here i have added sample story board scenes. [image]

I need to do add cells[Quantity rate and amount(0.00)].

Workflow : When i click on add(+) button it will direct to another scenes. it is a static table view. when i add data from there text fields and click save button(bar button). that data should appear in a new cell in following screen.

Answer (score 1):

Static and dynamic are opposites. If you intend to change the table view contents, do not use a static table view.

Comment: So please post me a solution to add dynamic cells to same view controller

Comment: I already answered that. You are starting with a static table view (as is clear from your screen shot, which says "static content". Don't. You can't add cells dynamically to that. Start with a table view with a prototype cell. The screen shot will then say "prototype content". Now you can do whatever you want, in the normal way. Please don't make me say the same thing over and over; it's pointless. The facts won't change just because you don't like them.